# if sup(A)≤ sup(B), then for every a ∈ A. there is b ∈ B such that a≤ b

Tags: real-analysis

if sup(A)≤ sup(B), then for every a ∈ A. there is b ∈ B such that a≤ b, is it true or false?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Try considering examples where $\sup(A)=\sup(B)$.

Comment: not the same, but related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697610

Comment: A and B are both bounded subsets of R
my friend says that it is true by using lemma1.3.8 from understanding analysis book which let $\epsilon$=sup(B)-sup(A) greater and equal to 0, then there exist an element a ∈ A satisfying sup(B)-$\epsilon$<b, then we could get sup(A)<b, since sup(A)=x, a ∈ A, a ∈ R, then a<=sup(A)<=b which means a<=b

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is not true, and here is a counterexample: $A = [0,1], B=(0,1), \sup(A) = \sup(B), a=1$